# Access Webapp (HTML, JS, CSS) on S3 via API-Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, proxy, api-gateway

I am able to access the index.html of my webapp via API-Gateway, but how can it use the JS and CSS files, that are stored in the same S3-Bucket?

Comment: What's the use case?

Comment: I have got an angular-app in a S3-Bucket. Via API-Gateway (URL) I access the index.html of the S3 Bucket, which works. However, it does not have access to the CSS and JS files.

Comment: Why through API gateway? You can simply make the objects public and access directly from S3. Either way, if you really need to go through API gateway, as long as your API gw has access to those objects then it should be able to access them all, regardless of their suffix

Comment: "Why through API gateway?" Well, custom domains is one great reason.

Comment: @JohnVandivier and why not use custom domains in combination with AWS S3? One can easily deploy a website statically using s3 and custom domains.

Comment: it may simplify deployment, particularly if you are using a monorepo pattern to deploy back end and ui simultaneously. See solution #1 from my answer which actually allows a static site and a back end to both be deployed with custom domain and not use S3 at all (although you can do so if u like).

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three approaches:

1. [aws-serverless-express](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express) will allow you to serve an express api through Lambda, which can integrate with API Gateway. You can use this approach to statically serve a ui application with `express.static` from express. This way you don't need S3 at all and you can server either a static site or non-static server side rendering.
2. Again, using aws-serverless-express, but this time create an express service which calls out to S3 using the [aws-sdk](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/).
3. A third option is you can set API Gateway up to use S3 proxy as pictured below

There may be other ways to do this using Cloudfront or Route 53 for orchestration instead of API Gateway, particularly if you are ok to have UI and back end on different domains then you allow some CORS requests. I personally prefer approach #1 because the infrastructure is simpler.

[image]